# Can't create table with FOREIGN KEYs in MySQL (DDL)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, ddl

Usually I worked with PostgreSQL and never had a problem, but now I need to work with MySQL and I experiencing some troubles.
I am creating a table in database user_main_db. There is some problem with Foreign keys, phpMyAdmin always gives me next error:

> 1005 - Can't create table 'user_main_db.user_main' (errno: 150) (
>
> engine=InnoDB&page=Status&token=136fdbb820093986c79180b24adb304d">Details...)

This is the table I am trying to create in database user_main_db:

```
CREATE TABLE user_main
(
uid INTEGER,
fn VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
ava VARCHAR(255),
gender tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
dob DATE NOT NULL,
country_id INTEGER, 
PRIMARY KEY (uid),
FOREIGN KEY ( uid ) REFERENCES user_basic_db.user_basic(uid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE            CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY ( country_id ) REFERENCES countries_db.countries(country_id) ON DELETE CASCADE   ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

This is table user_basic in database user_basic_db:

```
CREATE TABLE user_basic
(
uid INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
email VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
password VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (uid)
);
```

This is table countries in database countries_db:

```
 CREATE TABLE countries(
    country_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    )
```

The strange thing is when I define the table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE user_main
(
uid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES user_basic_db.user_basic(uid)  ON DELETE CASCADE ON    UPDATE CASCADE,
 VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
ava VARCHAR(255),
gender tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
dob DATE NOT NULL,
country_id INTEGER REFERENCES countries_db.countries(country_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON  UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

the query runs successfully but FOREIGN KEYS are not created, when I open 'relational view' there are no references to uid and country_id and I can make insert to user_main(country_id) even if there is no country with such id.
Please help someone. Thank you.

Comment: Your last issue(strange foreign keys) is not strange for me , i don't the reason but mysql does not append foreign keys to column when the syntax you mentioned is used.

Comment: thank you for help! I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the MySQL manual about [foreign key constrains](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> If you re-create a table that was dropped, it must have a definition
>   that conforms to the foreign key constraints referencing it. It must
>   have the right column names and types, and it must have indexes on the
>   referenced keys, as stated earlier. If these are not satisfied, MySQL
>   returns error number 1005 and refers to error 150 in the error
>   message.

Sounds familiar, doesn't it!?

Better drop the tables and create it new with a well formed syntax, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`country_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `country` (`country`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `user_basic` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `user_main` (
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fn` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ava` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`uid`),
  KEY `user_main_ibfk_2` (`country_id`),
  CONSTRAINT testc1
  FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`country_id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT testc2
  FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `user_basic` (`uid`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

This should do the job.

Comment: Works like a charm for me. Do you have InnoDB enabled on your MySQL server? Did you really drop all those tables before executing these three queries?

Comment: Yes, sure I did. But what do you mean InnoDB enabled? I use MAMP on my iMac. Everything is by default.

Comment: Try `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_innodb';` - if it returns a YES, then InnoDB is enabled. Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: The query returns YES. Version I suppos is MySQL 5.5.

Comment: Hm.. slowly I'm getting out of ideas. Try adding the `CONSTRAINT` declaration in the statement (see my updated SQL for creating the table `user_main` and see if this works if we're forcing your DB to use a specific name.

Comment: Guys, I feel so stupid )))) I have found the problem. I have created table countries with capital 'C', so mySQL could not find table with lowercase letter. But anyway Bjoern especially, thank you very much, you have shown me RIGHT syntax for MySQL, it is very useful. And everyone else thank you very much!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has the concept of `storage engines`, that provide different capabilities and performance profiles. I suspect you created your tables with the MyISAM storage engine, which doesn't provide foreign keys.

If you use the INNODB engine, I suspect your foreign keys will work as intended.

**Edit**

You set the storage engine by providing the `ENGINE=InnoDB` clause **after** the closing bracket of the `CREATE TABLE` statement